# Simulate permissions for non-login user

Tags: linux, shell, permissions, file-permissions

I want to perform some actions on behalf of some non-login users, such as e.g. `www-data` or `uwsgi`. My purpose is to test some permissions, check what dirs they can modify etc etc.

Is there a recommended way of going about this, other than creating a shell and password for them and `su` ?

**edit**:

When I try to `su` to the specific user with `sudo`:

```
admin@ip-192-10-30-111:~$ sudo su www-data
This account is currently not available.
admin@ip-192-10-30-111:~$ cat /etc/passwd | grep -i www-data
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
admin@ip-192-10-30-111:~$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to create a shell and password for them, you can simply run `su` as root and use the `--shell` argument of `su`.

To run a bash shell as `www-data` run:

```
su --shell /bin/bash www-data
```

as root.